# how can i solve this raw query

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i am trying to fetch some data from my db using laravel db and it's throwing error

```
$most_purchased_day = (int)Data::select('type')
                      ->whereDate('created_at', '=', date('d'))
                      ->groupBy('type')
                      ->orderByRaw('COUNT(*) DESC')
                      ->first()->network_id;

$most_purchased_day = (int)Data::select('type')
                     ->whereDate('created_at', '=', date('d'))
                     ->groupBy('type')
                     ->orderByRaw('COUNT(*) DESC')
                     ->first()->network_id;
```

i expect output to be most bought item based on network id

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object

Comment: Trying to get property 'network_id'* of non-object

Comment: @user7310495 can you show us the migration or model of that **Data table**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first user is not retrieved because the carbon instance of `created_at` does not match `date('d')`
Change your code to use the [today()](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-today) helper instead

```php
$most_purchased_day = (int)Data::select('type')
                      ->whereDate('created_at', '=', today())
                      ->groupBy('type')
                      ->orderByRaw('COUNT(*) DESC')
                      ->first()->network_id;
```

Assuming an Eloquent model created today

```
App\Data {
     id: 1,
     created_at: "2019-09-22 13:15:19",
     updated_at: "2019-09-22 13:15:19",
   }
```

`date('d')` only returns an integer that is the day number on the current month (22) and can not match `2019-09-22 13:15:19` see [PHP:date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

#### If you want to get records created on any day that is the number of the current day regardless of month and year

use [whereDay](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#where-clauses)

```php
$most_purchased_day = (int)Data::select('type')
                      ->whereDay('created_at', '=', date('d'))
                      ->groupBy('type')
                      ->orderByRaw('COUNT(*) DESC')
                      ->first()->network_id;
```

From [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#where-clauses)

**whereDate / whereMonth / whereDay / whereYear / whereTime**

The `whereDay` method may be used to compare a column's value against a specific day of a month:

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereDay('created_at', '31')
                ->get();
```